# react-native bundle failed on first attempt

Tags: react-native

It was my first attempt to start react-native by: react-native run-android on windows 10
My java version is 8.
The node cmd fails and does not perform bundle step completely

```
1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
```

these are steps the bundle asked to try but I haven't installed watchman or any other stuff it's looking for
I installed node android and java

could someone help me out on how to run this?
[this is the error on node cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8hSH.png)
[This is the error result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKSUh.png)

Answer (score 0):

React Native 0.56 is broken [[1]](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20331#issuecomment-406928234) [[2]](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19953) on Windows.
For the time being, you can create your new RN app in version 0.55.4 using:

```
react-native init myApp --version 0.55.4
```